# Java programme works perfectly in NetBeans, but exits unexpectedly when trying to run

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, jar

I've run into a weird problem today. I'll try to describe the steps I'm making as detailed as possible.

1. I've created a Java application in NetBeans. The application runs without exceptions when running within NetBeans by clicking Run Main Project. The total duration of a complete run is about 1min.
2. When building the project I see the following option in the output window of NetBeans:

   To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:

   ```
   java -jar "C:\java_libraries\PrxJobCommunicator\dist\PrxJobCommunicator.jar"
   ```
3. So i open the command prompt (Windows 7), enter this command + supply a mandatory integer argument and press enter
4. The application starts running, runs for a couple of seconds and exits without any message whatsoever.
5. the application writes to a text file at different points in the code, so I'm able to trace the output up to the point when it stops running. I've deliberately put some extra calls to the file writer method in order to find where the programme continues/exits but to no avail. Seemingly the programme simply stops running on a certain line and that's it.

I really don't know what the problem can be: the application runs fine in NetBeans and fails without any message whatsoever when starting from the command line.

Shall I check anything special in NetBeans? Do you know of any special technique to debug a jar file if it's started from the command line?

Any clues are welcome.
Thanks, Andras

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is a difference in the classpath when the app is run from NetBeans, and when it is run from the command line.
There must be some kind of exception that is being thrown, have you got an outermost
`catch (Exception )` block in the main method?

You could try to debug the application using "remote debugging", although you won't be debugging over a network, you can still use this method to catch the breakpoint started at the command line in NetBeans.
Here's an article that explains how to do remote debugging with NetBeans http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/debugging-java-applications-with-netbeans/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've found the error as described in my other comment on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans by default uses your project folder as the working folder. It means when you run your program from console you have to CD C:\java_libraries\PrxJobCommunicator
then run java -jar "C:\java_libraries\PrxJobCommunicator\dist\PrxJobCommunicator.jar"

If above fails check the java version used in your command prompt. java -version 
It has to be same as the one used by netbeans.

Finally the library path. Are all the dependent jars placed in the dist folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've actually found the source for the error. it's so embarrassing that i'm considering changing profession :-) 
I forgot that i'd redirected the stdoutput to a string variable which in turn was also filtered: any output that didn't match a certain pattern was discarded so when the application was screaming for a licence key file, the message was never picked up. My try-catch blocks didn't pick up the error message because it wasn't an Exception object, but a simple message.
Anyway, i'll continue working now :)
//Andras